# adb Cannot detect HTC One X after I updated to 4.2.2

Tags: eclipse, adb

I am on Mac OS X. I was happily debugging on my HTC One X when I was on Android 4.0. I recently updated to 4.2.2 and now the adb has stopped detecting my HTC Once X. Did anyone else have same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

`Settings` -> `More` -> `Mobile network sharing`

Uncheck `HTC Sync Manager`

Now everything is working fine

Comment: Good to know that you fixed it :)

Answer (score 7):

You're "right".  To solve it is very tricky (and it's HTC's fault).

Go to "Settings" -> "Developer options" -> uncheck "USB debugging" -> check "USB debugging" again -> then phone asks for permission: "Allow USB debugging" -> confirm it by tapping "OK".

Now you have it detected.  So the problem is because it needs the explicit permission after upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I fixed it the other way. I've posted my solution bellow.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It solved my problem. After I updated my android version on my HTC One, it automatically unchecked 'Allow USB debugging 'option. All I need is to check it again.

Comment: I've tried this, but I never get the "Allow USB debugging" prompt to show when connecting to a Mac (though it works as expected on Windows).  As for the Mobile network sharing, its set to off.  I'm having this issue on both the HTC PN072 and the HTC One_M8